# How get json_decode value (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I have json like this:

```
[{"lt":"1","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]},{"lt":"2","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]},{"lt":"3","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]}]
```

but how can i get lot value? i just can get lt value, im using this code:

```
 $string = json_encode($results) // $results is my json data;    
 $json = json_decode($string);
 foreach($json as $value){
 echo $value->lt;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lot is array hence you cannot use `echo`

```
$results = '[{"lt":"1","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]},{"lt":"2","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]},{"lt":"3","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]}]';
$json = json_decode($results);
echo '<pre>';
foreach($json as $value){
    echo "\nlt value: ";
    print_r($value->lt);
    echo "\nlot value: ";
    print_r($value->lot);
}
```

Result:

```
lt value: 1
lot value: Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)

lt value: 2
lot value: Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)

lt value: 3
lot value: Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

http://phpio.net/s/8sy

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the lt

```
 $string = json_encode($results) // $results is my json data;    
 $json = json_decode($string);
 foreach($json as $value){
   // this one is for the iteration of the lot value 
   foreach($value->lot as $lot) {
       echo $lot;
   }
   // if you want to collect the lot as a list you cant 
   echo $value->lot;
 }
```